# How to setup custom sorting (highest rated posts) based on wpreviewsite.com plugin?

Tags: wordpress, sorting, plugins, customization, posts

This question is regarding a WordPress website that uses a premium plugin.

Currently have sorting enabled for "most views" based on the WP-PostViews plugin in functions.php:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse13483_init' );
function wpse13483_init() {
add_rewrite_rule( '(.+?)/order/views/?$', 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&v_sortby=views&v_orderby=desc', 'top' );
}
```

However now trying to add support for "top rated" sorting based on the wpreviewsite.com plugin. This is definitely possible, somehow, because this plugin comes with a "top rated posts" widget that uses the following code (among other less-important code... fairly sure this is the key part):

```
//Post sorting
$sort = get_option('rs_sort');
if ($sort == 'rating') {
add_filter('posts_fields', 'rs_weighted_fields');
add_filter('posts_join', 'rs_weighted_join');
add_filter('posts_groupby', 'rs_weighted_groupby');
add_filter('posts_orderby', 'rs_weighted_orderby');
} else if ($sort == 'comments') {
add_filter('posts_orderby', 'rs_comments_orderby');
}
```

Would appreciate any insight on how to take these WordPress post filters and turn them somehow into a PHP function or otherwise that can become a new rewrite rule in functions.php. Thanks!